# How to rescale coordinates $(x,y)$ after transforming a rectangle image to square.

Tags: geometry

I originally have a $720\times1280$ rectangle. Suppose I reshape it into $400\times400$ while keeping the aspect ratio fixed (**padding the rectangle as done in films**)

I have a
set of coordinates $(x,y)$ corresponding to the square region. I want to transform these coordinates back to the $720\times1280$ region. These coordinates can only be found inside the rectangle superimposed in the square region.

How do I do these? These coordinates are usually from the predicted bounding boxes of a neural network. The input to the network is reshaped into square, keeping the aspect ratio fixed.

---

I  have tried multiplying the coordinates by the vector [720/400, 1280/400] but it gives offsets.

Answer (score 0):

find the percentage of the $(x,y)$ coordinates in the $400\times400$ by:
$$ \% X=\frac{x}{400} \quad,\quad \% Y=\frac{y}{400}$$

then find the corresponding percentage in the new ratio by:

$$ \% X \times1280 =x_{ new} \quad,\quad \% Y \times720 =y_{ new}$$

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if the square region is padded with zeros to preserve the aspect ratio of the rectangle region.